# how to identity if user clicked on a date in DateTimePicker calendar

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datepicker, datetimepicker

I don't want the date to change when user clicks out of the calender without clicking on a date. The problem is One Date is always selected when the datepickercalendar opens up. I am looking for something similar to DateSelected event in the Calender control

I have a class that derives from DateTimePicker which uses custom format with a spacechar string for to have empty field for DateTimePicker.

I found an article in stackoverflow with same issue but the solution doesnot work. I don't have enough points to place comments either (unable to find the link now :( )

As far as code this is what i have

```
Public Class CustomDP
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker

    Public Sub New()
        CustomFormat = " "
        Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnValueChanged(eventargs As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnValueChanged(eventargs)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnCloseUp(eventargs As System.EventArgs)
        Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short
        MyBase.OnCloseUp(eventargs)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDropDown(eventargs As System.EventArgs)
        Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        MyBase.OnDropDown(eventargs)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: @Plutonix How can I be sure that the datevalue entered was selected by clicking on the date in the calendar within datepicker(first couple of sentences in the question). What I don't want is, user clicks on the calender pages to the next month and doesnot select a date and closes the calender by click anywhere else on the form. I need similar functionality like dateselected in calender control but hate to have extra controls like textbox and more additional validation associated to the date format

Comment: the two options below (3 if you include the CP NullableDateTimePicker) ensure the user clicks on the DTP, but in different ways.  the ShowCheckBox is simple; while the longer code version is something like what you will need to subclass the DTP.

Comment: @Plutonix tried three different project demos in codeproject 1) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5428/Nullable-DateTimePicker 2) http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/623035/Complete-Date-Time-Picker-Control 3) DTP_Example. In all of them date will change when user clicks on the left/right arrows on the calender (want to prevent this change) I tried the first solution but still the same issue

Comment: ok, i get it now.  thats going to be much more problematic because that is how it works - like a numericupdown, there is always a valid value selected, and when the month changes so does the current value.  I cant see how that can be changed because it is all internal.

Comment: **actually**  try the CheckBox thing with `ShowUpDown` set to true.  they spin thru each field instead of using a drop down calendar, so it  eliminates the issue yet another way, but makes it a little more cumbersome to pick a date.

Comment: @Plutonix I do appreciate the time and effort you took to answer the questions but going without a calender is not an option for my requirements so i will go to the calender control with a separate textbox to display the selection and use dateselected event. Just put the above comment about spin thru for an answer (i will give it some credit)

Comment: it is already explained/offered in the shorter answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already at least 1 `DateTimePicker` control on CodeProject which allows for a Nullable Date.  But there is a simpler method than that.

In design, set the `ShowCheckBox` to True.  Then when the form loads or you are resetting fields, set `Checked` to False.  This makes the DTP look disabled which is a little unfortunate, but when the user opens the DTP, the Checkbox is automatically checked.  So, all you need to do to see if they picked a date, is to evaluate the `Checked` property.  The disabled appearance ends up indicating that the value doesnt really count, if they should happen to uncheck it after selecting a valid date.

If you use the smaller version (`ShowUpDown`), the control **is** disabled until they first click the checkbox, then select a field to spin thru.  You will still get a value changed event for each change of each field, but thats how it is supposed to work.  The control always has a valid date value so you dont have to check against `Nothing` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to be sure a date is picked is to "mirror" the DTP value in code (which is likely what you'd end up doing in a subclassed control).  This is only a partial solution because the control will set a date value if they flip thru months.  Its just how the control works.

```
Public Class Form1

    ' "mirror" dtp value vars
    Private myFromDate As Date = Date.MinValue
    Private myToDate As Date = Date.MaxValue

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        ResetDates()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ResetDates()
        ' reset the dates for repeated entries,
        ' ValueChanged event will fire
        myFromDate = Date.MinValue
        myToDate = Date.MaxValue

        ' the button only enables for valid dates
        Button1.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckDates()

        ' signal that all is well
        Button1.Enabled = ((myFromDate <> Date.MinValue) AndAlso
                          (myToDate <> Date.MaxValue) AndAlso
                          (myToDate > myFromDate))

        ' debugging while a DTP is open can be...problematic
        Console.WriteLine("from {0} to {1}  {2}", 
                       myFromDate.ToString, myToDate.ToString, 
                       (myToDate > myFromDate).ToString)

    End Sub

    Private Sub dtp_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                        Handles dtpFrom.ValueChanged, dtpTo.ValueChanged

        Dim dtp As DateTimePicker = CType(sender, DateTimePicker)

        Select Case dtp.Name
            Case "dtpFrom"
                If dtp.Value = dtp.MinDate Then
                    myFromDate = Date.MinValue      ' used when Resetting
                Else
                    ' myFromDate <> Date.Min acts as a flag
                    myFromDate = dtp.Value          
                End If

            Case "dtpTo"
                If dtp.Value = dtp.MaxDate Then
                    myToDate = Date.MinValue        ' Resetting
                Else
                    myToDate = dtp.Value            ' user pick
                End If
        End Select

        CheckDates()
    End Sub
```

Its a bit more code than the `ShowCheckbox` method but something like what you would need for subclassing.  If you subclass the DTP, you'd likely raise a new event from this ValueChanged event when the mirror variable <> `Date.Min|Max` and CheckDates would not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

An old thread but maybe someone finds this useful... If you're looking for DTP that opens "blank" and selects date only If user selects It, then this is (in my opinion) best and simplest option:

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Form.Load

        DTP_Example.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        DTP_Example.CustomFormat = " "

End Sub

 Private Sub DTP_Example_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DTP_Example.ValueChanged

        DTP_Example.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Long

 End Sub

 Private Sub DTP_Example_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DTP_Example.KeyDown

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
            DTP_Example.Value = Now
            DTP_Example.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
            DTP_Example.CustomFormat = " "

        End If

    End Sub
```

This way you have DTP "blank" on open, and displays date If you select some. Also you can delete dates with "Backspace" or "Delete" keys and even select same date as before, which makes DTP simmilar behavior like combobox/textbox. Same "Backspace" behavior as in textbox/combobox can be achieved too, with a little more coding (using another Textbox to manually enter Dates), but in my opinion this is good enough. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    Label42.Text = String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTimePicker1.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_DropDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.DropDown
    RemoveHandler DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged, AddressOf DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged
End Sub

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_CloseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.CloseUp
    AddHandler DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged, AddressOf DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged
    Call DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note you are answering a very old and already answered question. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).