# WinForms DatePicker to display a blank text box before date selection

Tags: vb.net

My program has a need to display a text box that is blank before the user selects a date.  A calculation is based on the date in the text box and often we find the user leave the text box with the original date.
The controls in the WinForms DatePicker does not allow any configuration that will accomplish this using VB.Net.

Comment: Are you asking about a DTP that starts out blank?  Hard to tell what the textbox has to do with the DateTimePicker part.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to have a DateTimePicker not have a Value (which must be a valid DateTime). If there is no reasonable default value you can set it to, you could set its initial value to something that can't be valid for your application and then verify that the user has changed it to something that is valid.

Comment: @Blackwood there is a Nullable DTP at CodeProject, if that is what the OP is after.  Almost as easy to use a magic date like `1/1/1970` as the signal nothing has been selected.  [There is also this "trick"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23727442/1070452) using `ShowCheckBox`

Comment: @Plutonix I hadn't come across that on CodeProject. I think that might be what the OP has in mind.

Comment: It apparently has developed some issues in Windows 7.  The `ShowCheckBox` or magic date tricks more or less serves the same purpose