# How to send the datetimepicker value to textbox, only when clicking the date, specific days or year of the month

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datepicker, datetimepicker

Everytime I double click the datetimepicker, it automatically send its values to the textbox. Now, I want to send the value of DateTimePicker in the Textbox, only when I click the date, specific days or year of the month?

[image]

Here's my vb.net code:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_DOB_CloseUp(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1_DOB.CloseUp
   TextBox1_Date.Text = DateTimePicker1_DOB.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Please see [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)  Regular site users know how to filter posts based on the tags to find/read the posts in topics that interest them.  Does the ValueChanged event do something closer to what you want?

Comment: You can use `ValueChanged` event of `DateTimePicker1_DOB`.

Comment: I tried the ValueChanged but if I click the current date, nothing appears to the TextBox and if the rows in the dataGridview has no date, the problem is the current date appears on the textbox.

Comment: I want to act like jQuery DateTimePicker.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Assure user clicked a Date using a DateTimePicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726994/how-to-identity-if-user-clicked-on-a-date-in-datetimepicker-calendar).

Comment: @Plutonix I hope I could see the windows form screenshot from [Assure user clicked a Date using a DateTimePicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726994/how-to-identity-if-user-clicked-on-a-date-in-datetimepicker-calendar).