# Saving DateTimePicker to DB

Tags: vb.net

I have a DateTimePicker on my form, and date should be saved ONLY IF user selects some date....In other words, DateTimePicker opens with current date and time displayed - that's fine. But If user doesn't click on control, nothing should be saved in my DB. Can this be done, maybe just setting some property ?

My code:

```
  Using con As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection("Data Source=MyDB;User Id=Lucky;Password=MyPassword;")

            con.Open()

            Using cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand()

    Const SQL As String = "INSERT INTO MYTable (DTP_Field) VALUES(: date_time)"

                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("date_time", DTP_Example.Text))

                cmd.CommandText = SQL
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                MessageBox.Show("Date saved")

            End Using

        End Using
```

Any help appreciated !

Comment: Your question (the text) has nothing to do with updating or saving a date, but program flow control.  You'll have to add code to detect when they have changed the value - of course, if they are happy with the value already there, the app will seem broke if it only saves when the DTP *changes*

Comment: Yes I know my code doesn't do what I want. My problem is that I have 4 datetimepicker's, and all of them should not enter any data if user doesn't choose anything...But I don't know how to do this...What about just showing blank value on form_load, is this possible ?

Comment: [Assure user clicked a Date using a DateTimePicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726994/how-to-identity-if-user-clicked-on-a-date-in-datetimepicker-calendar)

Comment: Not sure how this helps me. Text of my DTP allways get's saved in Oracle. I need to change my code for saving first, then this would come handy, imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found simplest solution to this...

1. Set DateTimePicker on Form_Load to show "blank" with changing format of It:

> DTPExample.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
>
> DTPExample.CustomFormat = " "

2. If user selects any date from DateTimePicker, then change format back in ValueChanged event:

> DTPExample.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Long

3. You have to make sure If user doesn't select anything from DateTimePicker that you don't save Date to DB. In my case (working with Oracle) this needed to be done like this:

> Dim SaveDate
>
> ```
>  If DTPExample.Text = " " Then
>         SaveDate = DBNull.Value
>     Else
>         SaveDate = DTPExample.Value
>     End If
> ```

4. And finally, you set attribute for Oracle DB with that:

> cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("date_time", SaveDate))

Output of this is - when form loads, DateTimePicker opens "blank". If you don't click It, nothing will get saved in Date field of your DB. But If you do, DateTimePicker will display a value in It, and that value will be saved in DB when you'll perform save.